# Curl API request value in body always null

Tags: json, curl, http-post, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have the following controller  I am trying to use Curl to test it.  The problem is that fiscalId is always null its not reading my post body from curl.

Controler:

```
  [Route("api/token")]
  public class TokenController : Controller
  {
    [HttpPost("changefiscal")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeFiscal([FromBody] long fiscalId)
    {
      //fiscalId is always 0
    }
  }
```

I have checked the documentation [here](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58) which says to use the -d parameter and post it as a json object. Unfortunately thats not working

> curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/data

I have tried

```
curl -d "fiscalId=21875" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX" -X POST -i http://localhost:5000/api/token/changefiscal
```

and

```
curl -d "{"fiscalId":"21875"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX" -X POST -i http://localhost:5000/api/token/changefiscal
```

and

```
curl -d "{"fiscalId":"21875"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX" -X POST -i http://localhost:5000/api/token/changefiscal
```

and

```
curl -d "{\"fiscalId\":\"21875\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX" -X POST -i http://localhost:5000/api/token/changefiscal
```

and everything else i can think of

I can see in the log that it appears to be sending it

> - Rebuilt URL to: POST/
> - timeout on name lookup is not supported
> - getaddrinfo(3) failed for POST:80
> - Couldn't resolve host 'POST'
> - Closing connection 0 curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'POST'
> - timeout on name lookup is not supported
> - Trying ::1...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - Trying 127.0.0.1...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#1)
>
>   > POST /api/token/changefiscal HTTP/1.1
>   >     Host: localhost:5000
>   >     User-Agent: curl/7.53.1
>   >     Accept: */*
>   >     Content-Type: application/json
>   >     Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjI2OTAzNzc0NjYyNzc4RDM1MzE2QUUwQUU1MjIyQUU1REIzM0M0NUEiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiJKcEEzZEdZbmVOTlRGcTRLNVNJcTVkc3p4Rm8ifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE1MTA1NjcxNzMsImV4cCI6MTUxMDU3MDc3MywiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjpbImh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMC9yZXNvdXJjZXMiLCJ0ZXN0YXBpIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6IlNlcnZpY2VBY2NvdW50QWNjZXNzIiwic3ViIjoiMjEyNDg1ODIiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1MTA1NjcxNzMsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwibmFtZSI6ImxpbGF3IiwiZS1tYWlsIjoibGlsYXdAZWcuZGsiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJvcGVuaWQiLCJwcm9maWxlIiwidGVzdGFwaSJdLCJhbXIiOlsicGFzc3dvcmQiXX0.Q_oJ-xOIKdTtGoRqJbtNjwLV82cQQLhJUVl2Ey-4riZdp45rPIrmfOw9VdknUOLpm8RYZ0iLFC31gCpn1vKb4zLiTmBuTuzYsKxnAvf-UkCj1L8soH4W2lCvx560bZeS7B67tJ4nK9t36OiMLQY4m-_NRTSRBs5QtsXBd5VQGPsTpxf_MxVbQm6Hj6Ot3FGRIa08gmwD3iEr9vsCU6732InbGzU26wtm-WLWp_A_k66Z29G8ms_U8x6gg-aOlQG9_0v_DEjTXCkKNcgWoL0IvaCC0psiYkdIjQxaOwz-e_fcqXpKEFmuoSqmGd1l-eMl3HimOomdOHwqploWGxnJ4Q
>   >     Content-Length: 7
> - upload completely sent off: 7 out of 7 bytes

However when i check fiscalId its always 0 i even tried to change fiscalId to a string and its just null.

Comment: Who ever voted this closed i hardly call it a typographical error When all the documentation says to send is as a JSon string.   I would more call it something strange with how .net core handels parsing the body

Answer (score 2):

When you POST data as JSON object, like `-d '{"fiscalId": 21875}'`,  your action method should expect some simple class with corresponding properties. In your case:

```
public class Dto
{
   public long fiscalId {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeFiscal([FromBody] Dto data)
```

Comment: I cant change this method description but that might explain why it cant read from a json object body

Answer (score 0):

Finally after more then an hour of playing with this I got it even though the content-Type is json its just sent as a string `"'21875'"`  even though all the documentation shows sending it as JSon.  For some reason the API isnt able to read it as a JSon Object but expects it just to be sent as a string.

```
curl POST -v -d "'21875'" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX" http://localhost:5000/api/token/changefiscal
```